# Problema ao realizar requisição HTTP no Android

Tags: java, android, http

Eu consigo fazer uma requisição HTTPS normalmente num app, porém não funciona quando é HTTP. Teria que configurar algo no Android Studio para que consiga fazer a requisição HTTP?

O código da minha classe responsável pela requisição está abaixo. Estou usando o Android Studio 3.4.2

CarregaDados.java ( HttpService )

```
package com.projetos.conexaoapi;

import android.os.AsyncTask;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class CarregaDados extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    String dados = "";
    private final String urlParam;

    public CarregaDados(String urlParam) {
        this.urlParam = urlParam;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
            //URL url = new URL("https://brasilapi.com.br/api/feriados/v1/2021");
            //URL url = new URL("https://viacep.com.br/ws/01001000/json");
            URL url = new URL(urlParam);

            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line = "";

            while (line != null){
                line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                dados = dados + line;
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

        MainActivity.twDados.setText(this.dados);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

O Manifest do Android possui uma propriedade chamada [`android:usesCleartextTraffic`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#usesCleartextTraffic), que permite ou bloqueia requisições HTTP (não criptografadas). A partir da API 28, o valor padrão passou a ser de "não permitir", conforme citado [aqui](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config#CleartextTrafficPermitted):

> A partir do Android 9 (nível de API 28), a compatibilidade com texto simples é desativada por padrão.

Conform [essa resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50834600/8839059), temos algumas opções abaixo. Elas estão ordenadas da opção mais recomendada para a menos recomendada.

### 1. Utilizar HTTPS

Essa é a melhor opção. Se o domínio permitir, você pode (e deve) usar a rota HTTPS ao invés da HTTP para que os dados trafegados sejam criptografados.

### 2. Permitir HTTP num domínio específico

Caso o domínio não permita requisições HTTPS, você pode criar uma configuração para que o Android permita HTTP nesse domínio específico.

Crie um arquivo em `res/xml/network_security_config.xml` com o seguinte conteúdo:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">seudominio.com</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

E modifique o `AndroidManifest.xml` para utilizar a configuração criada:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        ...
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        ...>
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

### 3. Permitir requisições HTTP para qualquer domínio

Caso você não saiba o domíno que precisará utilizar HTTP em tempo de compilação do código (por exemplo, você possui um endpoint dinâmico configurado pelo usuário), você pode permitir o HTTP em todos os domínios.

Para isso, basta modificar o valor da propriedade `android:useCleartextTraffic` no `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        ...
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        ...>
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

### 4. Reduzir o nível do `android:targetSandboxVersion`

Se você configurou um nível diferente do padrão para o [`android:targetSandboxVersion`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element#targetSandboxVersion), pode ser necessário reduzi-lo para `1`. Conforme documentação:

> Quanto maior o número da versão do sandbox, maior o nível de segurança. O valor padrão é 1. Você também pode defini-lo como 2. A definição desse atributo como 2 alterna o app para outro sandbox SELinux.
>
> As restrições a seguir se aplicam a um sandbox de nível 2:
>
> - O valor padrão de `usesCleartextTraffic` na configuração de segurança da rede é falso.
> - O compartilhamento de Uid não é permitido.

Então, você pode remover a propriedade do `AndroidManifest.xml` ou modificá-la para `1`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest android:targetSandboxVersion="1">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia. quando a requisição não é segura vc precisa criar permissões especiais para ela.
Faça o seguinte

crie um arquivo xml em `res/xml` com o nome `network_config.xml` neste formato abaixo com a lista dos dominios em http q vc vai requisitar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">viacep.com.br</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">melhordosgames.com.br</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

depois disso vai no seu manifest e na sua application adicione 2 parametros:

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_config"
```

vai ficar algo assim:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_config"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

dai é só testar ? com isso vc autoriza conteúdo não seguro a ser trafegado pela internet

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno pessoal, vou testar aqui, depois comento com foi... o Detalhe é que estou conectando numa Rede Interna, numa API REST ( Spring Boot ), e por padrão a Requisição é http, num browse o retorno funciona normal, no Postman também funciona, numa Aplicação ReactJS também, porém no Android teve este detalhe, demorei a perceber que o detalhe era devido ao tipo de conexão http que estava indo, conforme citado.

Comment: Deu certo colocando esta linha no AndroidManifest (  android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" ), depois colocar as autorizações conforme as urls que utilizar. Muito obrigado, valeu mesmo!

Comment: @JoséAparecidoPereira não esqueça de dar voto +1 se esta resposta foi útil para você. E também de marcá-la como favorita caso você julgue como a melhor solução. Analise a outra resposta também e der o feedback. Assim, você ajuda outros devs que tem o mesmo problema a encontrar e melhor solução.

Comment: Olá, quando tento votar, devido eu postar pouca coisa por aqui, acaba não validando... eu geralmente resolvo o que preciso vendo outros posts a respeito do assunto, vou ver como melhorar isso... obrigado!

Comment: @JoséAparecido você não pode votar por conta da sua reputação, mas ainda pode aceitar a resposta, isso marcará sua pergunta como resolvida. Leia mais em [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/100416)